# <p:layout> and <p:fileUpload> not working on page refresh

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions, joinfaces

I'm facing a peculiar issue. I have a single page app based on SpringBoot, JoinFaces and PrimeFaces 6.2. The page primarily has an Accordion with two tabs.

```
Tab 1 - has a <p:fileUpload> //user uploads XML files using it
Tab 2 - has a <p:layout> //the selected XML file's content is displayed here, segregated into two <p:layoutunit>
```

After the Accordion I have a toolbar with a submit button by which I send the selected XML to a back end service that converts the XML data into a PDF. I then display the PDF using PrimeFaces-Extension's `<pe:documentViewer>` inside a `<p:dialog>`

**The issue:**
The flow works fine till I click on refresh on the browser. If I refresh the page, I notice the CSS for the `<p:fileUpload>` and `<p:layout>` goes wrong. (Also, the `<p:fileUpload>` stops working as well).

[image] [image]

**Observation 1:**
When I compare the HTML source, before and after the refresh I see that after refresh, the page doesn't have these includes under `<head>`:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/javax.faces.resource/fileupload/fileupload.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.2" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/fileupload/fileupload.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.2"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/javax.faces.resource/layout/layout.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.2" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/layout/layout.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.2"></script>
```

Any idea what may be causing this and how to correct it?

**Observation 2:**
The bean KWOMTesterController is currently marked with `@Named`. If I annotate it with `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` as well, then the UI issue is resolved, but the `<pe:documentViewer>` complains of missing PDF (the bean has a `DefaultStreamedContent` field, where I store the PDF data).

**Code snippet:**
Here is my XHTML snippet:

```
<p:accordionPanel id="mainpanel"  activeIndex="0" binding="#{kwomTesterController.accordian}" cache="false">
    <p:tab title="Select target environment and KWOM XML">
        <p:panel>
            <p:fileUpload update=":mainform" label="Select KWOM XML"
                value="#{kwomTesterController.selectedFileName}" multiple="false" skinSimple="false" auto="true"
                fileUploadListener="#{kwomTesterController.handleUpload}" style="margin-top:20px" mode="advanced"/>
        </p:panel>
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab title="View/Edit selected KWOM XML " >
        <p:layout style="width:100%;height:360px;">
            <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="false" size="400" header="Configuration section">
               ...
               ...
               ...
            </p:layoutUnit>


            <p:layoutUnit position="center" header="Data section" style="overflow:hidden !important">
               <p:inputTextarea  rows="20" cols="138" autoResize="false" style="resize: none;" id="contentarea" 
                    value="#{kwomTesterController.data}" />
            </p:layoutUnit>

        </p:layout> 
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

Comment: How do you refresh the page? And what is your version info of JSF and springboot? And did you inspect the network traffic? Errors?

Comment: @Kukeltje  I'm just either hitting F5 or the reload icon on Chrome. Same issue on IE and FF as well. Springboot - 2.1.0 (via Springboot-starter-parent 2.1.0) and I see javax.faces-2.3.7.jar getting bundled inside the FAT jar that maven is building. Network traffic shows no errors at all.

Comment: In fact, I see in the Network...that there is request going out for the layout.css.xhtml and fileupload.css.xhtml only when I access the page for the first time. When I hit F5, there is no request going out under Network, for those two particular resources.

Comment: Changing the bean to javax.faces.view.ViewScoped, shows those two resources requests correctly under Network, each time I hit F5 (I guess, that's how it should be). However, making the bean ViewScoped, breaks off DocumentViewer's behavior.

Comment: Normally I'd just say, please create a [mcve] with also reading https://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info. But I'm in a good mood so I'll ask other things as well... Are you using a template? If so can you add a dummy (hidden) fileUpload and layout in there?

Comment: And do you have errors on the browser console? https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3457

Comment: Not using templates..no errors in browser console either. I would surely try creating a minimal reproducible example (that's the reasonable thing to do). For the moment, I took out the JS and CSS for `fileupload` and `layout` from PF6.2 jar and dumped it into my code-base and referred them from the XHTML. (very bad solution though, from future perspective, but solves the purpose right now).

Comment: Do you use an `update="@all"`?

Comment: Nope. Using specific updates only for interested components, throughout the XHTML.

Comment: Then there is only one thing remaining (and already mentioned): [mcve]